# Vue 3 Vuex how can I force a callback function to run asynchronously

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

I am using Vuex with Vuex-persistantstorage and I have a variable representing application mode. When the mode is changed I want to do several things (lets call this f()) such as open sidebars, change route, etc. and some of those things will cause a change to other Vuex variables.

I have tried making the changes f() in a computed property between the UI element and the store mode variable.

I have also tried using a watcher on the mode variable and making the other changes f() there.

In all cases I get an error "do not mutate Vuex store state outside mutation handlers". If I removed the actions that cause Vuex state other than the mode to change then the problem goes away. All my changes to the Vues variables are in a mutation handler using store.commit.

After much debugging it appears that f() is called synchronously during the reactive code that is executed when mode changes and that Vuex treats all Vuex variables as part of one big variable so that modification to a second Vuex variable during the modification cycle of the first Vuex variable is a bad thing, hence the error.

How can I create a callback that executes after the entire reactive cycle of the Vuex variable is complete?

Comment: Can you provide some code, ideally the exact code that is triggering the error? Otherwise we're just guessing what the problem is from a vague description of a more complex problem.

Comment: I am still trying to reproduce it in a small example.

Answer (score 0):

> "do not mutate Vuex store state outside mutation handlers"

This error only happens if you are changing Vuex state not from a mutation, or if the mutation is mutating state in an asynchronous way (i.e. after the mutation function has returned).

> All my changes to the Vues variables are in a mutation handler using store.commit

Clearly the state is being mutated outside of a mutation, though.

> After much debugging it appears that f() is called synchronously during the reactive code that is executed when mode changes and that Vuex treats all Vuex variables as part of one big variable so that modification to a second Vuex variable during the modification cycle of the first Vuex variable is a bad thing, hence the error.

Not sure if your conclusion is correct. It shouldn't matter when `f()` is being called, as long as the state mutations are occurring synchronously within a mutation function.

> How can I create a callback that executes after the entire reactive cycle of the Vuex variable is complete?

This is probably not the solution ([XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)).

It would be helpful if you could provide the line of code where the state mutation is happening that triggers the error.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce it with a small example. I will keep trying. I have stepped through the code in the debugger and it does happen way down inside the commit function. And if I remove the function call in the watcher it doesn't cause the error. I am pretty new to javascript and debugging it is not easy because I am stepping through vue reactivity code forever it seems like.

Comment: It's happening inside the commit function? You wouldn't be getting that error then, unless you're doing something asynchronous in there (in which case you should use an action instead). Are you using `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `setTimeout`, or something similar?

Comment: I never could reproduce it in a small app. I eventually changed the way I was doing things in general.